# Any thoughts on why this Swift code does not compile?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

Anything wrong with this syntax?

```
protocol Serializable
{  
    init(dictionary:[NSObject:AnyObject])  
}
```

I'm getting an error with this line. I'm following [this](http://stripysock.com.au/blog/2014/7/11/fetching-and-parsing-json-with-swift) example.

I just can't seem to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: That code compiles without problems in my Xcode 6 beta 4. Perhaps you are using an older beta release? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Is it the equivalent of   init(dictionary:(NSObject, AnyObject))? by the way? because this works

Comment: No, `(NSObject, AnyObject)` is a tuple, not a dictionary. Can you provide the exact error message and the Xcode version? - In previous releases, the syntax was something like `init(dictionary:Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>)` .

Comment: Martin thanks for your help i'm actually on beta2, so i'm going to upgrade right now and will let you know what happens! It says syntax error insert ',' to fix which of course doesn't work. Stand by though installing now!

Comment: [NSObject:AnyObject] syntax was introduced in beta 3 or 4, don't remember which, in beta 2 syntax would be Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntactic sugar for Array and Dictionary [changed in beta 3](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=3). This code won't work in the first or second beta, but will work in a newer version.

If you want the code to work in an earlier version, just remove the syntactic sugar:

```
protocol Serializable
{
    init(dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)
}
```